# How do I play Dice Poker?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I found two minigames in the first area of The-Witcher-2, an Arm-Wrestler, and someone who wants to play "Dice Poker". While the former is simply explained in the in-game help, there was no information on how to play Dice Poker.

What do the symbols on the dice mean?

What do the (unlabeled!) circles under the bet screen do? (I believe the left is forfeit, and the right is call, but I'm not positive)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the a very good explanation for [Dice Poker](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Dice_poker) including statistics. It's for the first Witcher game, but it's mostly the same, except for those symbols. One circle is 1, two circles is a 2, and for the rest count the points, so the triangle is 3, etc.

The unlabeled circles are a glitch. Restarting your game should fix it, but in most menus in Witcher 2, space is accept and Esc is reject.

Comment: Just lost a game, He had 6 6 3 3 3,
I had 6 6 4 4 4 What am I missing?

Answer (score 9):

You can ignore the symbols, inside the symbols the dice are numbered 1-6. The rules are very similar to poker, you need to get a better "hand" than your opponent.

The best combinations are from best to worst:

- Five of a kind
- Four of a kind
- Full house
- Big street (values 2-6)
- Small street (values 1-5)
- Three of a kind
- Two pairs
- One pair

After the first die roll you can choose which dice you want to throw again. Be careful when throwing the dice, only move the mouse slightly or you might throw a die outside the game area and lose it for this game.

Comment: This sounds like Yahtzee.  Is it "street" or "straight"?  (Yahtzee uses the latter).  Also, a large straight is usually 1-5 or 2-6, and a small is 1-4, 2-5, or 3-6.  Just wondering if this is definitely different?

Comment: @Matthew It's from the manual, and street is just translated as I got the german version.

Comment: Ah cool. I'll check mine later.