# How to win dice poker?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I keep losing every single time no matter how many times I try. Even when I get a Five of a Kind V the opponent got Five of a kind VI and beat me!

It feels like the game is rigged. Is there a way to win?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I play Dice Poker?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22561/how-do-i-play-dice-poker)

Answer (score 6):

Well as any other gambling its mostly **luck** there are only few things that can help you increase the odds:

**Throw dices low and in the middle** of the board if you go around the egdges and throw too strong it can happen that your dice gets out of the board and you will be left out with great disadvantage.

**Know the winning combinations**(highest to lowest):

- Five-of-a-kind – five dice showing the same value
- Four-of-a-kind – four dice showing the same value
- Full House – a pair and a three
- Six-high strait – dice showing II, III, IV, V and VI
- Five-high strait – dice showing I, II, III, IV and V
- Three-of-a-kind – three dice showing the same value
- Two pairs – dice showing two matched pairs of values
- One pair – dice showing a single matched pair of values

You can also save game before playing dice poker and by loading game if you lose you can ensure that you **get the lead**,it will lower the chances you playing all the rounds.

And if you  really lose every game like 10 in a row there could be some bug or glitch especially if you are using unofficial mods...on the other hand if you win here and there you could be plainly unlucky :(

Read [this](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Dice_poker_in_The_Witcher_2) maybe you will find something you didn't know.

Comment: well I Knew all that... managed to finish the quest after about 10 save/loads for each foe. thats kinda rediculus.